# Regex: Accept digits and atleast 1 star

Tags: java, regex, validation

String should contain digits and atleast one asterisk. Please help me with the regex.

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("\\d", "12345678*")); //true
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("\\d", "1234****")); //true
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("\\d", "123456789")); //false
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("\\d", "abc45678*")); //false
```

what should be the correct regex pattern ?
I tried different patterns like `[0-9](?=.*_)`. but no luck.

Thank you!

Comment: Show some effort please. What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Can asterisk be anywhere or only at the end?

Comment: Does it mean you need to match a string starting with one or more digits and that ends with one or more asterisks? `.matches("\\d+\\*+", "123456789")`? Note that `(?=.*_)` requires an underscore, not asterisk.

Comment: asterisk should be at the end

Comment: Why did you try a lookahead and look for an underscore? I can't see underscores mentioned anywhere in the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
.matches("\\d+\\*+", "123456789")
```

Here, the regex matches the whole string that starts with one or more digits and one or more asterisks after these digits.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pjhYB2/1).